# Installing Basic on Linux

Tags: .net, basic

How to install Basic/VB on Fedora Linux?? I really wanna try it out.

I've tried:
`sudo dnf install basic`
`sudo dnf install visual-basic`

Comment: There are many BASIC interpreters available for Linux. VB.net is (IIRC) not one of them, as it requires the full Visual Studio which haven't been ported to Linux.

Comment: With that said, why do you want to learn BASIC? Even VB.net suffers from some rather archaic constructs that haven't changed much the last 50 years or so, when BASIC was first invented. There are probably much better beginners languages available these days. Python seems like a popular beginners choice.

Comment: I don't want to learn it. I just wanna try it out

Comment: I don't see closing this question as unclear as being mandatory for reviewers.

Comment: This question has answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067894/vb-net-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET and Visual Basic 6.0 do not function in Linux, even under Wine, however searching pkgs.org finds the following BASIC packages for Fedora.

- [basic256](https://pkgs.org/download/basic256) - educational BASIC programming environment for children

  BASIC-256 is an easy to use version of BASIC designed to teach young children the basics of computer programming. It uses traditional
  control structures like gosub, for/next, and goto, which helps kids easily see how program flow-control works. It has a built-in graphics
  mode which lets them draw pictures on screen in minutes, and a set of detailed, easy-to-follow tutorials that introduce programming concepts through fun exercises.
- [yabasic](https://pkgs.org/download/yabasic) - Yet Another BASIC interpreter

  Yabasic is a traditional basic-interpreter. It comes with goto and
  various loops and allows one to define subroutines and libraries. It does simple graphics and printing. Yabasic can call out to libraries
  written in  C and allows one to create standalone programs. Yabasic runs under  Unix and Windows and has comprehensive documentation; it is small, simple, open-source and free.

Neither of these packages can be found at the official [Fedora Packages](https://packages.fedoraproject.org/) website. On the other hand both basic256 and yabasic can be installed in Ubuntu from the default Ubuntu repositories (e.g. `sudo apt install  basic256`  or `sudo apt install  yabasic`), so maybe you'd want to spin up an
Ubuntu VM just to be on the safe side.

The BASIC programming language package descriptions were copied from the results of `apt show basic256 yabasic`

Comment: yabasic is not nearly as capable of VB. But yeah, why install Basic at all :D